# How do I fix the error "Floating point exception (core dumped)"?

Tags: c++

I am receiving an error that says "core dumped" when running my program. I'm a beginner, and I'm not sure how to fix it. It prints out correctly up until part 1-4

```
int main() {

  string unshuffledDeck = "AAAA222233334444555566667777888899990000JJJJQQQQKKKK";
  string shuffledDeck = "";
  srand(time(0));

  for ( ; unshuffledDeck.length() != 0 ; ){
    // (1-2a) Generate a random number between 0 and the current unshuffled deck size 
              minus 1 to select the card we are going to move
    int randomIndex = rand() % (unshuffledDeck.length() - 1);

    shuffledDeck = shuffledDeck + unshuffledDeck[randomIndex];

   unshuffledDeck.erase(randomIndex, 1);

  } // end for

  string playerHand = "";
  string dealerHand = "";

  // (1-4b) Deal the cards by moving them from the deck to the player and dealer hands
  do {
    playerHand += shuffledDeck[0];
    shuffledDeck.erase(0,1);
  } while((playerHand.length() - 1) < 2);

  do {
    dealerHand += shuffledDeck[0];
    shuffledDeck.erase(0,1);
  } while((dealerHand.length() - 1) < 2);

  // (1-4c) Print out the deck and hands to verify cards moved in the appropriate order
  cout << shuffledDeck << endl;
  cout << "player: " << playerHand << endl;
  cout << "dealer: " << dealerHand << endl;

}
```

Comment: This works without giving a floating point exception: `int main(void) {return 0;}`

Answer (score 1):

`int randomIndex = rand() % (unshuffledDeck.length() - 1);` this cuses this core dump when `unshuffledDeck.length()` equals to `1` division by zero is hapening. So you should cange it to `int randomIndex = rand() % unshuffledDeck.length();` because modulo operator `a % b` returns value from `-b` **exclusive** to `b` **exclusive** e.g. `(-b,b)` in your case all numbers are positive so it returns value from `zero` **inclusive** to `b` **exclusive** e.g. `[0,b)`